# How to store value in NullBooleanField from Django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to insert data into a `NullBooleanField()` from a Django form, however, only `'True'` is ever added.

I have printed the cleaned data from 3 different fields from the form and it looks as follows:

```
True
False
None
```

(Which is what I would expect it to look like - as I selected 3 different options)

This is what the form fields look like:

```
MY_CHOICES = [(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No'), (None, 'N/A')]

field_1 = forms.ChoiceField(
    required=True,
    choices=MY_CHOICES,
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer),
    label="Field 1"
)
```

And this is what the fields in the model looks like:

```
field_1 = models.NullBooleanField()
```

I don't understand why the data always inserts as `'True'` when I check in Django admin.

In Django admin, the choices are as follows: `"Yes, No, Unknown"`

So I have tried changing the form choices to read as follows:

```
MY_CHOICES = [('Yes', 'Yes'), ('No', 'No'), ('Unknown', 'N/A')]
```

But yet again, this does not work.

Can anyone suggest what might be the issue here?

**EDIT -- Showing how this is saved to model**

```
new_entry = ModelName(
    field_1=form.cleaned_data['field_1'],
    field_2=form.cleaned_data['field_2'],
    field_3=form.cleaned_data['field_3'],
)
new_entry.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Here is how to solve the issue.

```
forms.NullBooleanField(
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRendererSpace,
        choices=CHOICES),
    label='...',
    required=False
)
```

NullBooleanField needs to be used when dealing with NullBooleanField in the model